# Create subfolders in Team Queries in VSTS 2008 using Team Explorer or Web Access

Tags: visual-studio-2008, subdirectory, team-explorer

Is there a way to create subfolders in the Team queries in VSTS 2008 using Team Explorer or Web Access or command line tool? I would like to put the queries in different categories, one per team of developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding subfolders in TFS2008 is not supported. But you can do this in TFS2010. Moreover one should be able to assign permissions per folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 2008, but you acn do this in VS2010 Team Explorer.  It's in the right-click context menu on Team Queries.